What is the Shortcut Key I Accidentally Pressed that Triggered an Unknown Screen?

I accidentally pressed a shortcut key, and an unfamiliar screen appeared on my computer. I’m not sure which key combination caused this. How can I identify the shortcut key I pressed, and what steps can I take to prevent this from happening again? Any help would be appreciated!

This looks similar to the pictographs section in Emoji&Symbols (at the bottom of the Edit menu). Which browser is this, on which version of macOS?

Character viewer - my command is Cmd/Ctrl/Spacebar but i don't know if that's the actual default. If someone can check & also advise where they hide the pref on current macOS [I'm well out of date these days] then add as an answer. It opens to the last state you had it set when it was last closed, btw.

@Tetsujin That seems to be the same as Emoji&Symbols, at least Cmd-Ctrl-Space opens this for me. See also https://www.macworld.com/article/607237/character-viewer-macos.html

Yeah, it's the same thing - toggles if you click the icon top right. It calls itself character viewer when it's not on emoji & symbols. I actually always have it on the full version, so that's the name I'm used to. Key command opens it however you last had it set - per app. iirc, it used to be called Character Viewer in the top menu too, before they renamed it emoji & symbols.

Yup, Character Viewer in Snow Leopard - idk when it changed. I'm getting old ;)
